# Classification of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an open region $\Omega$ of $\mathbb C$, and a function $f$ that is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Writing $f = u + iv$, I am asked to prove that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic on $\Omega$.

I know that a function $\rho$ is harmonic if:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

As $f$ is holomorphic, then $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions on $\Omega$, that's:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

and:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Taking partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$ respectively:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y}$$

and:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = - \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y \partial x}$$

We can do the same thing for $v$.

Hence, if the mixed partial derivatives of $u$ (resp. $v$) are equal, we have the desired result. This requires (I don't know if there are some weaker requirements) that $u$ and $v$ be of class $C^2$ on $\Omega$.

But in my lecture notes, I have only one necessary condition for a function to be holomorphic, namely that CR conditions be satisfied.

I searched for an answer, and I found on Wikipedia that an analytic function is infinitely differentiable. I know from the lecture notes that differentiability and analyticity are the same thing for complex valued functions. So, I can deduce for this problem that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, so that both $u,v \in C^{\infty} \subset C^2$.

The problem is that I am not too sure about this because of one thing:

Our professor stated many theorems in the following manner: "*Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic and has a **continuous derivative** on...*". Why would she have to suppose that the derivative is continuous, while differentiability already guarantees that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the theorem you are stating is Looman Menchoff theorem which is more stronger than the theorem your prof stated but it is difficult to prove. have a look at it [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math220/Narasimhan-LM.pdf)

Comment: When studying complex analysis, it often starts with the definition of holomorphic functions, then it takes some work and time to prove that these are always $C^\infty$. So at the early stage of the course, this exercise is interesting to play with CR equations.

For your exercise, simply assume that the functions are $C^2$ which is in fact not restrictive.

Comment: @BolzWeir got your question now thanks for clarifying. Generally they assume that since professors do not want to use unproved theorems. Though they are finally going to prove all holomorphic functions are analytic and therefore infinitely differentiable that the extra assertion is actually unnecessary